# Merging dataframes, dropping column and set index

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes like this:

```
import pandas as pd

left = pd.DataFrame({'id1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'val1': [1, 2, 3]})
right = pd.DataFrame({'ID2': ['a', 'c', 'd'], 'val2': [4, 5, 6]})

  id1  val1
0   a     1
1   b     2
2   c     3

  ID2  val2
0   a     4
1   c     5
2   d     6
```

I want to merge these two dataframes, doing an inner merge, drop `ID2` and then also use `id1` as a new index. My desired output looks like this:

```
    val1  val2
id1            
a       1     4
c       3     5
```

I currently do this as follows:

```
res = pd.merge(left, right, left_on='id1', right_on='ID2', how='inner').drop('ID2', axis=1).set_index('id1')
```

which gives me the desired output.

My question is whether there is already an option that allows me

a) to drop a key column when an inner merge is performed as there will then be two identical columns

and/or

b) to directly set the index to one of the key columns used for the merging process.

Is the way I do it now the way to go or is there anything smarter/a built-in for this already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with parameters `left_index` and `right_index`, (`how='inner'` is omited because default value) but first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) in both `df`:

```
res = pd.merge(left.set_index('id1'), 
               right.set_index('ID2'), 
               left_index=True, 
               right_index=True)
print (res)
   val1  val2
a     1     4
c     3     5
```

Solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), is necessary add parameter `join` for `inner` join:

```
res = pd.concat([left.set_index('id1'), 
                 right.set_index('ID2')], axis=1, join='inner')
print (res)
   val1  val2
a     1     4
c     3     5
```

Answer (score 5):

One option is to set the key columns as index before joining, this will keep only one key column as index in the result:

```
left.set_index("id1").join(right.set_index("ID2"), how = "inner")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

out of the three solutions provided the 'merge' solution works fastest:

```
pd.merge(left.set_index('id1'), right.set_index('ID2'),left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: That is the accepted answer, or am I missing something?! Would you mind adding the speed comparisons?

Comment: yes you are right, all three answers work fine but i am telling that the solution provided using 'merge' is fastest...please see the image i have attached in answer...please forgive if i havent been articulate enough

Answer (score 0):

[image: Speed Comparison]

please see the speed comparison...the first answer i.e. the one using merge is fastest